# How to convert the type from _csv.reader to rdd in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I first need to use csv.reader to read the rdd file to remove the double quote in the rdd file. And then I need to transform the csv.reader file into rdd type. I tried to use sc.parallelize, but I found that all the content are disappeared.

And here is my code:

```
rdd_units = sc.textFile('file.csv')
rdd_units.take(4)
```

**output of rdd_units.take(1):**

*['"apple","banana","orange","cherry","blueberry","kiwi"']*

```
rdd_units_=csv.reader(rdd_units.collect(),delimiter=',')

rdd_units_1=sc.parallelize(rdd_units_)

rdd_units_1.take(1)
```

**output of rdd_units_1: [ ]**

But I want the output of rdd_units_1 to be:['apple','banana','orange','cherry','blueberry','kiwi'] and I don't know why rdd_units_1 becomes empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataframe.

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test.csv")
df.columns

['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'cherry', 'blueberry', 'kiwi']
```